# Asus eeepc 1215N: console garbage after kernel boot

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, console, gpu, asus

I am trying to revive an old [Asus eeepc 1215N](https://origin-www.asus.com/Laptops/eee_pc_1215n/) (as donation for a student in the time of online classes), at first trying with Ubuntu 20.04. The computer "features" nvidia optimus (dual GPU) and is normally functional when booting (I can run BIOS setup and the boot manager).

The moment the Linux kernel takes over (kernel and initrd are loaded), the screen turns to garbage, as shown here:

[image: garbage screen]

The garbage stays constant (i.e. does not look like damaged but progressing boot messages), does not disappear even after an hour (when I'd suppose live USB will have booted into X11 already). I tried several Linux distros (Ubuntu 20.04, 18.04, 16.04, CentOS, Arch, Debian stable 32bit netinstall, ...), it happens the same for all of them. I tried booting with `nosplash`, `nomodeset`, `nouveau.blacklist=1`, `i915.modeset=0` I picked up at various forums, with always the same result.

The only case which did not result in this damage was FreeDOS (which reported "invalid opcode" at some point and froze, though...).

Wiki pages about installation of various distros on these machines (such as [Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_Eee_PC_1215N)) don't mention anything similar; they mostly deal with power-management of the dual GPU or how to fix broken X11 drivers.

Ideas?

Comment: What happens if you try to boot a live Linux, e.g. Ubuntu ISO `dd`ed to a USB thumb drive?  (Also, please double check 32-bit vs 64-bit system / EFI in case you haven't done so already).

Comment: I was booting everything from Live USB (create via unetbootin, some via other tools - balena Etcher, IIRC). The boot manager would display fine (both text mode for unetbootin, semi-graphical for Ubuntu 20.04); the moment the kernel takes over, it is lost. No luck with 32bit either;  the CPU is 64bit capable, though.

Comment: On some of these old machines the CPU is 64-bit but the EFI is 32-bit. They are more difficult to boot. Perhaps this is one of those machines?

Comment: Everything is booting fine, in the legacy (BIOS) mode - it is from year 2010, after all. The grub/lilo/whatever menu appears, no problem at all. I will double-check, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the posterity, the issue was in the bootloader setting the video mode for the linux kernel; in that moment was the freeze with garbage screen happening. The trick to boot the machine is to:

1. have the bootloader use plain text mode (`GRUB_TERMINAL="console"` in `/etc/default/grub` for grub2); and
2. not change the video mode during the handover to the kernel (passing `gfxpayload=text`, or setting `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD="text` in `/etc/default/grub`; for the older boot protocol (linux16), the equivalent is passing `vga=normal` on the kernel command-line).

Kernel modesetting, later during the boot itself, is not an issue at all.

Installer/live USB with graphical grub (such as ubuntu 20.04) will not work, the installation itself had to be done in a different machine, then `chroot`ing into the installation, adjusting `/etc/default/grub` and runing `grub-update`. After putting the disk into the 1215N, it boots flawlessly.